# How is the transcription direction of RNA polymerase determined?

Tags: dna, rna, transcription, polymerase

When transcription factors attach to the DNA strand - How do they know in which direction they have to initialize the transcription by rna polymerase? Is it always read in the same direction anyway? What about those 'promoters'? Do they influence the transcription direction?

Comment: Do you mean by direction which of the two DNA strands is transcribed? Or do you mean whether the polymerase goes from 5' to 3', or from 3' to 5' on a single strand?

Comment: @MadScientist Although the first question is also interesting, the second one is the one which I am interested in at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transcription always proceeds in the direction 5' (5-prime) to 3' (3-prime) on the coding strand of DNA. Binding of both transcription factors and RNA polymerase to DNA depends on sequence motifs in the DNA. Transcription always happens in the same direction with respect to the chemical structure of the coding DNA strand, while the transcription direction with respect to the structure of the chromosome depends on which strand the coding sequence is found on (and thus which strand is defined as the coding strand for that gene).

Comment: Just to clarify, RNAP moves relative to the template strand from 3' to 5'. The transcript is polymerized from 5' to 3' and has the same sequence as the coding strand (except U instead of T).

Comment: Thanks, good point. The whole process is described, with figures, in an NCBI online book here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22085/

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can also communicate that an answer is useful by clicking the checkmark next to the answer, "accepting" it.

Comment: I don't think transcription always goes $5' \rightarrow 3'$ *wrt* to coding strand. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promoter_%28genetics%29#Bidirectional_promoters_.28mammalian.29

Comment: In that instance there are *two* coding strands, so the transcription still goes the same way with respect to each coding strand.

Comment: What about in negative-sense ssRNA in viruses?

Comment: I think that during _replication_ there was a subunit that ensured directionality, but I don't remember which. Maybe a similar situation occurs in transcription?

Comment: I think the more important thing to understand here is how these enzymes "know" what to do. I find it fascinating that the polymerase can actually move backward to perform error corrections. How do they know do do that? Is there some kind of biological software in an enzyme that tells them how to do these things?

Comment: user38945 "is right". Seriously: Any "promoter" is just a grain of sand in the strand, it's true that there are - right or left, from "that" promoter  - some nucleotides that define "its" direction, i.e. its directing.  (With my maths, two of them would suffice (as Polymerase is one trick pony, does from '3 to '5, always does it.))